# Give different file types different icons but have them open with the same program

Tags: windows-7, icons, file-types

I have several file types that I want to have open with the same program. I also want them to have different icons. When I set one file to have a different icon, it changes the icon for all of the different file types that the program opens. How can I do this?

I am using the [default programs editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/) on windows 7 home premium.

Comment: Thank You! Now how do I select your comment as the answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) to do what you want:

[image: 1]

See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/492237/change-application-associated-with-an-extension) if you want help.

Comment: How do I do this? I tried using the program in Win10 but it always changes both the .htm and .pdf icons together? Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

download [Types](https://softfamous.com/types/) and then:

- search for the extension
- double click it
- uncheck "Class"
- check it again and write whatever you want there and hit plus
- go to actions, write whatever you want (example: open) and hit plus
- browse for the default program
- close Types program to refresh windows regs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).